# Use Codeigniter and Kohana together

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, kohana

I'm building new site in Codeigniter 3. The old website is coded in Kohana framework (customer wished to build new site in Codeigniter)
The admin panel of old site is well done and I don't need to change them.
My question is: can I use the old admin and my new site both in one domain?
Have anyone any ideas or solutions?

Comment: if you don't maintained admin session in front site then you can put admin code(kohana) child directory or you can also run on subdomain `admin.domain.com`.

Comment: I tried put code to subdirectory 'admin' in main directory of site. In `.htaccess` file I added `RewriteRule admin/^(.*)$ /admin/ [L]`. When I call my site url it works properly, but when I call `mysitename/admin` I get `mysitename/404error`.

`Not Found

The requested URL /404error was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: You'll need to run them on separate domains/subdomains because of the way .htaccess works. It is probably possible to run them on the same domain but the amount of work you'd have to do to keep the two frameworks separated from one another is gonna be impossible. Just like the guy above suggested, put the admin on admin.domain.com and move the kohana code there and on the regular domain.com have the codeigniter. Simple.